# Many To Many relations Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, many-to-many, yii2-model

I need help with this code, I'm new to Yii2.
I'm building a sample project to start, and I don't know why my code gets the right result but doesn't save the ids I need into the many-to-many table for the relationship.
I started from this sample in the wiki: https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/708/book-has-author-many-to-many-relations-using-kartikselect2

My Model

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['anno', 'durata', 'flagdelete', 'categoriaid'], 'integer'],
        [['titolo', 'riassunto', 'regista', 'descrizione'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['attoriIds'], 'safe'],
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'titolo' => 'Titolo',
        'anno' => 'Anno',
        'durata' => 'Durata',
        'riassunto' => 'Riassunto',
        'regista' => 'Regista',
        'descrizione' => 'Descrizione',
        'categoriaid' => 'Categoria',
        'nome' => 'Attori',
    ];
}

/**
 * @var array
 */
public $attoriIds = [];

public function getdropAttori()
{
    $data = Attori::find()->asArray()->all();
    return ArrayHelper::map($data, 'id', 'nome');
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAttoriIds()
{
    return $this->attoriIds;
}

/**
 * @param $attoriIds
 */
public function setAttoriIds($attoriIds)
{
    $this->attoriIds = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn(
        $this->getAttdvd()->asArray()->all(),
        'attori_id'
    );
}

/**
 * @param $insert
 * @param $changedAttributes
 */
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    $actualAttoris = [];
    $attoriExists = 0;

    if (($actualAttoris = Attdvd::find()->andWhere(
        "dvd_id = $this->id"
    )->asArray()->all()) !== null
    ) {
        $actualAttoris = ArrayHelper::getColumn($actualAttoris, 'attori_id');
        $attoriExists = 1;
    }

    if (!empty($this->despIds)) {
        foreach ($this->despIds as $id) {
            $actualAttoris = array_diff($actualAttoris, [$id]);
            $r = new Attdvd();
            $r->dvd_id = $this->id;
            $r->attori_id = $id;
            $r->save();
        }
    }

    if ($attoriExists == 1) {
        foreach ($actualAttoris as $remove) {
            $r = Attdvd::findOne(
                ['attori_id' => $remove, 'dvd_id' => $this->id]
            );
            $r->delete();
        }
    }
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAttdvd()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attori::className(), ['id' => 'attori_id'])->viaTable(
        'attdvd', ['dvd_id' => 'id']
    );
}
```

My Controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Dvd();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

}

public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    //i think the problem is the line below
    $model->attoriIds = $model->AttoriIds;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

My form (that work properly):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'AttoriIds')->widget(Select2::classname(), ['data'=>$model->dropAttori, 'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Seleziona attori']])->label('Attori') ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad way because the making of that code in multiple models will make models dirtier. The better way is usage of a universal component that can manage relations in your models.  For example [yii2-many-to-many-behavior](https://github.com/voskobovich/yii2-many-to-many-behavior)

Comment: con you explain in short how this component work? there is no documentation or example online except for the github doc. Can you make an example that can possibly fit with my code?

Comment: i solved with the https://github.com/voskobovich/yii2-linker-behavior , because the one that you linked will be deprecated soon, but it worked after a lot of work, many thanks, and super easy to use!

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192).